# как из функции вывести масcив?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def row():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Recipes.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Car WHERE Car_ID = 1')
    row = c.fetchone()

    c.close()
    conn.close()

    a = []
    a.append(row[2])
    a.append(row[3])

    return a


print("Значения 1:" + row().row[2] + "Значения 2:" + row().row[3]) --- ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = row()
print("Значение 1:" + data[0] + " Значение 2:" + data[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Функцию можно чуток попроще написать:

```
def row():
  with sqlite3.connect('Recipes.sqlite') as conn:
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute('SELECT Field2 Field3 FROM Car WHERE Car_ID = 1')
    return curs.fetchone()

val1, val2 = row()
print("Значение 1:" + data[0] + " Значение 2:" + data[1])
```